# Runtime Error When Adding Picasso to Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, picasso

I am receiving the below error when i add picasso to the dependencies and i can't find out what how to fix it. please any help would be appreciated. i tried cleaning, rebuilding the project and got no error but when running the project, the error shows up.

app gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.mobprofs:retrofit-simplexmlconverter:1.1'
    compile 'rubygems:json:1.8.0'
    compile 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1:org.apache.commons.codec:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.picasso:picasso:2.5.2.3'
```

loader:1.9.4'
    }

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug] :app:preBuild
>   :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild
>   :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild :library:compileLint
>   :library:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE :library:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
>   UP-TO-DATE :library:preBuild :library:preReleaseBuild
>   :library:checkReleaseManifest :library:prepareReleaseDependencies
>   :library:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :library:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :library:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :library:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE :library:mergeReleaseAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :library:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :library:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :library:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :library:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :library:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :library:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE :library:compileReleaseJava
>   UP-TO-DATE :library:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :library:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE :library:compileReleaseNdk
>   UP-TO-DATE :library:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
>   :library:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
>   :library:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :library:bundleRelease
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAmulyakhareComAmulyakhareTextdrawable101Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72210Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72200Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable750Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComJpardogoMaterialtabstripLibrary110Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComPkmmteViewCircularimageview11Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareProjectOneLibraryUnspecifiedLibrary
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareItSephirothAndroidLibraryPicassoPicasso2523Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJava
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files
>   use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. :app:preDexDebug :app:dexDebug UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:dexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
> >       C:\Users\RZahr\AppData\Local\AndroidStudio\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat
> >     --dex --no-optimize --output D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectOne\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug
> >     --input-list=D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectOne\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
> >     Error Code:   2 Output:   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
> >       com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
> >     0xffff]: 65536        at
> >     com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)      at
> >     com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
> >           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
> >           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
> >           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)         at
> >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
> >           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)      at
> >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)      at
> >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)         at
> >     com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

gradle console error:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   0xffff]: 65536    at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)  at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
>     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
>     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)    at
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)     at
>   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>   >     C:\Users\RZahr\AppData\Local\AndroidStudio\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat
>   >     --dex --no-optimize --output D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectOne\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug
>   >     --input-list=D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectOne\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   >     Error Code:   2 Output:       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   >     com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   >     0xffff]: 65536        at
>   >     com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)      at
>   >     com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
>   >       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
>   >       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
>   >       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)         at
>   >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>   >       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)      at
>   >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)      at
>   >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)         at
>   >     com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: try this `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

Comment: i tried that and it was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the different libraries you have added to make sure they don't have colliding dependencies or that the libraries are correctly aded.

i have :

```
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.+'
```

to manually disable colliding library modules,follow this example :

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0@aar'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

**EDIT**

The case may be, also, that you have ran out of methods. yes, this can happen, don't worry! what you have to do is enable multidexing, also known as, enabling your android build engine to ignore the 65k methods limit and build more method files.

the steps are described here :

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

but i'll make a small resume.

you have to add this dependency :

```
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

and this line to your manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

finally, on your build.gradle file, you have to setup this configuration setting:

```
  defaultConfig {
        ...(your settings)

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: how do i know what libraries are colliding? is it showing from the error i posted?

Comment: it's not showing there, could you post the "red lines" of the gradle console to see where it breaks?  anyway, i usually check it by going to their github page and looking at the /libs folder or at their documentation.  colliding support libraries is the most common cause of my gradle errors on runtime.

Comment: please, could you post your complete Build.gradle file? i believe i know the cause of your problem.

Comment: thank you for your time. i didnt get what do you mean by ran out of methods?  do you mean because i added so many libraries?

Comment: yes, there is a limit on how many methods android can build without generating extra files, and sometimes too many libraries can go past the limit. it's not bad, ofcourse, as android devolopers website states : "If you have built an Android app and received this error, then congratulations, you have a lot of code! "