# Getting error when try to import picasso library

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I want to import picasso library to my android studio, but when i try that.
Android studio give me a message:

Error:(3, 0) Could not find property 'dep' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@71d5a575.
Open File

So how to fix it? I really need your help.
This is my app graddle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this another one:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hp.refomandaapps"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
  dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile project(":lib-release")
   compile project(":circleindicator-debug")
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
   compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

   }
```

Comment: could you comment compile project(":lib-release")
   compile project(":circleindicator-debug") just to try

Comment: Just an advice, Don't import entire google play service library, [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) import specifically.

Comment: @MinaFawzy sorry i dont understand what u say :(

Comment: dose the app was working before import picasso ?

Comment: @MinaFawzy yes the apps working as i expected before i try to import picasso.

Comment: @nikhilr57 why? this library automatically added when i try to add google maps api in my application. Sorry because i am a newbie android developer.

Comment: try multidex, https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html , this may be conflict with another lib or jar so multidex will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Here are my sample build.gradle files. Note that there are two build.gradle files, one under the app folder and one under the project folder.

The one under **App** folder looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.com.example.android.appname"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral ()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

I see that you don't have repositories tag in your gradle file. Try adding  that and see if that fixes the issue. 
The one under the **Project** folder looks like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

It might also be that different libraries are colliding and you have to enable multidexing. See this post for more info
[Runtime Error When Adding Picasso to Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133738/runtime-error-when-adding-picasso-to-gradle)
Let me know if this works. Good luck!

Comment: The problem in "Runtime Error When Adding Picasso to Gradle " is when you import too many library.
But my problem is Could not find property 'dep' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@71d5a575. Open File. Do youhave another solution for my problem? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try multidex this may be solve your issue

Module.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: did you upload your project to any site to check it , it may be error in your gradle and this can happen for many reasons

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand what you say, Do you mean you want to check my project?

Comment: yea you can email me or upload it to github

Comment: then upload it to check where exactly the issue